# is there a way to convert svg <line> to svg <path> in illustrator?

Tags: d3.js, svg, adobe-illustrator

I have a coworker using Illustrator to merge 2 svgs.  1 svg was using several `<path>` elements but these were converted to `<line>` elements.  I know there's a general algorithm for converting and svg `<line>` to an svg `<path>`.  For example, here's an example of doing that using D3.js:

https://www.dashingd3js.com/svg-paths-and-d3js

However, I was wondering if there was a more native way of doing this directly in Illustrator, through an Illustrator plugin or through some type of third party automated tool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make this, turning lines into compound path (right click + Make Compound Path). That change this:

```
<line fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10"
    x1="216.935" y1="158.508" x2="661.196" y2="166.705"/>
```

to this:

```
<path fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10"
     d="M661.196,166.705l-444.262-8.197"/>
```

Hope this help.